# How to capture all http requests in a classic asp application?

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic

I need to capture all HTTP requests in a classic ASP application.  I looked at Global.asa, but it doesn't have any event that fires for all HTTP requests.  Please let me know if I can even do that.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you want any request for your site e.g. http://example.com/foo.asp & http://example.com/bar.asp to go to the same page?   Or are you trying to set up a restful web service and want http://example.com/foo/id & http://example.com/bar/id  etc.?

Comment: I need to redirect all pages to to a a different application based on certain logic. e.g. example.com/foo.asp & example.com/somefolder/bar.asp to go to the same website.  But it is not a blanket redirect.  I need to check some criteria before redirecting.  I cannot do it on Session start.  It will only do it for the first time.  If the user has a bookmark, it won't work.

Comment: Try writing your function into the global.asa as an ordinary function/sub. You'll be able to call it from anywhere in your app.

Comment: Yes, by writing a function global.asa and abandoning session before redirect did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by writing a function global.asa and abandoning session before redirect did the trick!

Comment: I'm trying to implement a similar one. Do I need to call the global.asa function in all the asp pages in the application?

Answer (score 1):

You write an ASP script (I call it "redirect.asp" for now) that does all the checks and redirects. Then you have some options:

1.)  it in every existing .asp file

2.) Server.Execute "redirect.asp" before other code in every .asp file

3.) Make a rewrite rule, that redirects ALL requests to your redirect.asp

Comment: +1 for rewrite rule. Check out the [IIS URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).